# Is there a way to have formdata conform to an interface or type?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, react-typescript

I am creating a form in React with TS like so

*VendingMachine.tsx*

```
interface Drink {
    Drink: string,
    Money: number,
    Sugar: number
}

export default function VendingMachine(){
        
    const handleFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget); // This returns me form data from my <inputs />
        const fieldValues = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()) // This need to be of the shape of the Drink interface above
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        {
            ["Drink", "Money", "Sugar"].map(name => (
                <VendingMachineInput key={name} name={name} /> // <input /> component
            ))
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Get me a beverage!" />
        </form>
    )
}
```

`VendingMachineInput` component is nothing but multiple input types.

In my `handleSubmit` function in `VendingMachine` component I get an object by using FormData like so

```
{
    "Drink": "Tea",
    "Money": "2",
    "Sugar": "1"
}
```

But its inferred type is

`const fieldValues: {[k:string]: FormDataEntryValue} = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())`

My question is how to I convert this fieldValues in my handleSubmit function to be of the shape of interface Drink above?

Comment: You can assert with as : `Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()) as Drink`